# SQL Server : select a record from a window with criteria

Tags: sql, window, criteria, rank

I have an audit table in SQL Server which stores data like this for a single case:

**Example 1**

```
ID        CREATED                 MESSAGE               MEMO         USER
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A-123     08/02/2022 12:00:00     Generic Message 1     NULL         System
A-123     08/02/2022 12:05:30     Generic Message 2     NULL         System
A-123     08/02/2022 12:45:01     Reassigned to XYZ     NULL         System
A-123     08/02/2022 14:59:59     NULL                  Resolved     User XYZ
A-123     08/02/2022 18:05:05     Reassigned to XYZ     NULL         System
```

**Example 2**

```
ID        CREATED                 MESSAGE               MEMO         USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A-987     07/02/2022 12:00:00     Generic Message 1     NULL         System
A-987     07/02/2022 12:05:30     Generic Message 2     NULL         System
A-987     07/02/2022 12:45:01     Generic Message 3     NULL         System
A-987     07/02/2022 14:59:59     NULL                  Resolved     User XYZ
A-987     07/02/2022 18:05:05     Reassigned to XYZ     NULL         System
```

Using SQL I want to only select the ID value in these circumstances:

1. When there is a MESSAGE value of "*Reassigned to XYZ*" with a USER value of "*System*"
2. When point 1. occurs at an earlier time than the record that contains a MEMO value of "*Resolved*".

In the 2 examples above, example 1 would output ID A-123 because the 2 criteria have met, but example 2 wouldn't output anything because the "*Reassigned to XYZ*" MESSAGE value is after the timestamp of the "*Resolved*" MEMO entry.

I think I need to rank() and then do something but I can't work out what.

Comment: Take it in steps: write a CTE [A] that gives you only those records which are 'Reassigned to XY'  then a second CTE [B] that returns only those which are resolved.  then join the two together using FROM [A] LEFT JOIN [B] on A.ID = B.ID and A.Created < B.Created  returning only SELECT A.ID.  or use an exists.  similr concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a need for a window function here.  There are several ways to address this: here are but a few ***UNTESTED*** ways.

USING an `Exists` to limit data:  Get all XYZ, find any occurrence of a XYZ create date before a resolved data. and return that ID  multiple ID's would return if multiple "reassigned to XYZ' Id's exist.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TABLE
WHERE message = 'Reassigned to XYZ' 
  AND exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TABLE
                  WHERE memo = 'Resolved'
                    AND A.ID = B.ID
                    AND A.Created < B.Created)
```

Using `CTE's` and an `join`.  Similar to exists;   show any XYZID whose created data is < the resolve'd created dat a for a same ID.  Could have multiple rows returned

```
WITH XYZ as (SELECT ID, Created FROM TABLE WHERE message = 'Reassigned to XYZ'),
     Resolved as (SELECT ID, Created FROM TABLE WHERE memo = 'Resolved')
SELECT XYZ.ID
FROM XYZ
INNER JOIN Resolved
   on XYZ.ID = Resolve.ID
  AND XYZ.Created < Resolved.Created
```

You could use an `aggregate` as well I suppose and `case expression`

This assumes you could have multiple Reassigned to XYZ or resolved, and all it takes is for 1 XYZ to be before resolved for the ID to show up. only 1 ID would ever be returned if condition is met.

```
SELECT ID, 
       MIN(CASE when Message = 'Reassigned to XYZ' then create end) as MinZYZ,  
       MIN(Case when memo = 'Resolved' then create end) MinMemo
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MINXYZ < MinMemo
```

I suppose we could do the min/case expression in the having to eliminate the values from the select if needed... simply substitute the expression for the aliased column name used

you could use `cross apply` cross apply is a table value function which allows the sub query to run once per record in the left table and operates like an inner join in that if no records are found the record is eliminated.  So only records which are XYZ and have a resolved created data greater than the XYZ record will be present.

```
SELECT Distinct XYZ.ID
FROM Table XYZ
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID, Created FROM TABLE WHERE memo = 'Resolved' ORDER BY Created ASC) Resolved
   on XYZ.ID = Resolve.ID
  AND XYZ.Created < Resolved.Created
```

NOTES:

- Each has their own pro's/con's and assumptions.
- Depending on data volume indexes etc performance can vary with each as well
- Feel free to ask qustions about any or point out if they don't' work.  again UNTESTED so based entirely off of logical thinking and may not be with correct syntax or return correct results.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. The dataset isn't that big so I've gone with your first option using EXISTS, tested it and it works perfectly! I just needed to add AND User = 'System' after WHERE message = 'Reassigned to XYZ'. Thanks again!

Comment: @markthornton90 Pay close attention to edge cases where memo and message may have those values multiple times /multiple records for the same ID.  (if such situation exists) as it may not do exactly what you want in such situations.